# Convert WPF generate vertices to OpenGL vertices

Tags: opengl, directx, porting

I have large amount of vertices generated by WPF library/application. I am trying use these vertices values in an OpenGL application.

Basically, converting from DirectX LH co-ordinate to OpenGL RH co-ordinate system. I have read [Converting DirectX vertexes to OpenGL vertexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594682/converting-directx-vertexes-to-opengl-vertexes) post and changed the indices/faces to point first, third and second but to no positive result.

I haven't go any matrix values, so only thing I have done is changed the vertices order. Can any help me in finding a solution to this.

Here is a screenshot of the current result:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think you misunderstood the answer to that question. When it says flip the order of the vertices it means the order they are specified for a triangle, not changing (x,y,z) to (x,z,y). So for a triangle if you specify vertex 1 then 2 then 3 you would change it to vertex 1 then 3 then 2. It did say that you need to scale z in the negative direction so you would want to change (x,y,z) to (x,y,-z).

Comment: I changed the indices/faces to first, third and second, but to no luck, sorry made mistake in my previous post and also scaled z to negative

Comment: And what result *do* you get?

Comment: @Nico Schertler I'm getting proper shapes of the child meshes, but together the each child mesh are mis-placed in some rotation issue. That is, whole mesh has issue in rotation, root mesh/node shape and child meshes/nodes shapes have rotation issue wrt root mesh/node.

Comment: I might be missing some basic norms here

Comment: How can I share a image to show the difference in directx & openGL rendering?

Comment: You can't, because you don't have enough rep. Post a link to the image and I'll insert it into your question.

Comment: @Nico http://tinypic.com/r/2vilglz/8

Comment: It looks like you are losing some transformations. How have you defined the geometry in WPF and how have you transferred it to OpenGL?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I am using some third party library which generate this vertices, indices, normals and offset transform matrix in WPF. I don't have any idea internally, this is where I am unable find the right issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to bother with second part of vertex recalculation: index shuffling. It is very error prone. You can just set up GL rasterization to disable culling `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)` or change winding order `glFrontFace(GL_CW)`.
It is still rest for you to negate `z` coordinates or use additional rotation matrix, but that's much easier.

Issue shown can be unrelated to vertex recalculation. Looking to pictures it looks more like a transformation matrices bugs.